# Laravel 5.2 multiple tags insert not working

Tags: tags, laravel-5

I create a blog site with laravel5.2. when I insert to multiple tags I get this error message.

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()

code:
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

Please help me, how do I solve this error?

Comment: Have you created tags() relation in your POST model?

Comment: Yes, I use it belongsToMany('App\TagModel');

Comment: Make sure you don't have any typos and that this method is public.Apparently Eloquent can't access it and that's why it's trying to call it on the Builder object.